# Will drinking coffee affect my physique?

Tags: health

I am a 16 year old student who has decided to drink coffee so that I can study for a longer period of time at night but I am getting information that coffee can make me skinny. But what if I just a little bit of coffee, will it affect my physique?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coffee will make you lean?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2932/coffee-will-make-you-lean)

Comment: You're unlikely to become skinny all of a sudden from drinking coffee. Caffiene does raise the body's overall temperature, which can lead to increased fat loss but it only really applies to people that combine it with vigorous exercise. Coffee however will affect your looks, particularly in your face you'll notice a difference. Your face tends to look more aged after years of use. I'd say for the sake of your exams just go for it. It's not really going to effect you that much.

Comment: @Myles that's an interesting claim, do you have a source? I'd love to read more on that.

Comment: @Myles - I'm still youthful looking and I've been drinking a LOT of coffee for years,  Do you have a source for that?

Comment: I couldn't give you a source because it's an unconfirmed 'bro science' within the body building industry. If you look up for medical papers published on the matter, you'll find that the results are inconclusive. However, you do have weight loss products like Grenade Thermodetonator that contain massive amounts of caffiene in them and seem to swear by the fat burning results you get from the thermoregulation effects caffiene has on the body. This is why i commented it rather than 'Answered' because its not really a known or exact science. I wouldn't worry much just drink coffee for the exams :)

Comment: You know what else makes you look older in your face over years? Years of aging :'D

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of that would cause weight loss with black coffee consumption is if you eat less due to the appetite suppressant that coffee can be.

But then again, drinking more of anything is an appetite suppressant. Even water. On the flip side, you can gain a lot of weight if you ingest high-calorie confections, such as any ice-blended coffee drink.

So, my notes really only apply to black coffee drinkers.

It is true that caffeine makes it easier for you to expend more energy. In the short run.

Your body will eventually adjust to your daily levels of caffeine. You'll have to drink more and more to get the same energy effects. Eventually, you'll have to drink coffee just to feel "normal."

I personally believe this also applies to any weight-loss potential.

The overall effects on weight loss are likely minimal, but will vary depending on how your coffee habit changes your eating habits.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that depends on how much sugar and creamer you put into it.

For years I have added coffee to my sugar and creamer and haven't lost a pound. I like a little coffee in my sugar and creamer. However I then switched to cold brew, it's less bitter and allowed me to put significantly less sugar and creamer in and I started loosing weight.

Answer (score 1):

Stay away from heavy duty sugary creamers and you’ll be completely fine. Avoid sugar altogether, that will do more detriment to your physique than a little milk or half and half, not to mention ruining the flavors of the coffee whereas fats (like in half and half) enhance the coffee (unless it’s a very acidic coffee in which case I would drink it black). I’ve only ever added half and half and have never been worse for wear!